# How does p-adic metric notation work?

Tags: notation, p-adic-number-theory

I want an expression that returns the highest power of $5$ that divides $x-1$.

i.e. i want to return an element of $\{1,5, 25, 125,\ldots\}$

Is $\lvert x-1 \rvert_5$ correct notation for the 5-adic metric of $x-1$?

And does that mean that if $f(x)=\lvert x-1 \rvert_{1/5}$ then:

$f(26)=25$

$f(31)=5$

Or am I breaking the rules again?!

Is it more acceptable to use $f(x)=\lvert x-1 \rvert_{5}^{-1}$

Comment: I would think that the notation $|26-1|_5=1/25$ is normal for the metric.. Also, often $\nu_p$ is used to denote the exponential valuation. So $\nu_5(25)=2$, $\nu_5(30)=1$ and $\nu_2(48)=4$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks. But $1/25\neq 25$.  If I understand your proposition correctly I could use $5^{\nu_5(x)}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, you seem to want the reciprocal. Yes, both Matt's solution $|x-1|_5^{-1}$ and $5^{\nu_5(x)}$ will work.

Comment: ok thanks i will use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$| \cdot |_{1/5}$ does not satisfy the triangle inequality and therefore does not define a metric. $|\cdot |_5$ does define a metric though so I would write $|x-1|_5^{-1}$.

(I have actually never seen $|\cdot|_{1/5}$ used anywhere so the other way is certainly more common.)